# How to order multiple columns right to left in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, multicol, right-to-left

I am trying to display some Hebrew words in three columns on a Beamer slide.

Because Hebrew is a right-to-left language, the columns should be ordered right to left. However, the columns are ordered left-to-right by default since the main language is left-to-right (say English or French). In the example below, I add a `\raggedleft` command so that the words are at least aligned on the right side.

How can I get the columns in the correct order?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%Setting line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

%Multiple columns
\usepackage{multicol}

%Languages
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}{Ezra SIL}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Vocabulaire: Chap. 2}
    
    \begin{spacing}{1.25}
        \raggedleft
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \texthebrew{אַבְרָהָם
            
    אַהֲרֹן
    
    דָּוִד
    
    יְהוּדָה
    
    יהוה
    
    יְהוֹשׁוּעַ
    
    יוֹסֵף
    
    יַעֲקֹב
    
    יִצְחָק
    
    יְרוּשָׁלַ֫םִ
    
    יִרְמְיָ֫הוּ
    
    יִשְׂרָאֵל
    
    כְּנַעַן
    
    מִצְרַ֫יִם
    
    משֶׁה
    
    עֵשָׂו
    
    פַּרְעֹה
    
    צִיּוֹן
    
    שָׁאוּל
    
    שְׁלֹמֹה
    
    שְׁמוּאֵל
    }
        
        \end{multicols}
    \end{spacing}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like (with the columns in the incorrect order):

[image: slide with three columns in wrong order]

Comment: Why don't you use the columns environment from beamer? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations#Columns // You can always reorder manually ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is inspired by the answer by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, which explains that Beamer's own column environment uses minipages.

In the end, that other solution came close to working, but did not quite produce all the desired effects. There is an awkward balance between the choice of fonts, XeLaTeX vs. LuaLaTeX, babel vs. polyglossia, etc. Some combinations yield better rendition of certain fonts and, in particular, of the alignment of the Hebrew vowels, which is absolutely essential.

In short, XeLaTeX does not handle Beamer's column environment, but does produce attractive Hebrew text. Thus, conceding all the challenges of XeLaTex as raised in a comment, the optimal solution must work with XeLaTeX.

The solution that worked for me is to use minipages directly.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}

%Setting line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

%Multiple columns
\usepackage{multicol}

%Languages
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}{Ezra SIL}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Vocabulaire: Chap. 2}
    
    \selectlanguage{hebrew}
    
    \begin{spacing}{1.25}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
            אַבְרָהָם
                
        אַהֲרֹן
        
        דָּוִד
        
        יְהוּדָה
        
        יהוה
        
        יְהוֹשׁוּעַ
        
        יוֹסֵף
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
            יַעֲקֹב
        
        יִצְחָק
        
        יְרוּשָׁלַ֫םִ
        
        יִרְמְיָ֫הוּ
        
        יִשְׂרָאֵל
        
        כְּנַעַן
        
        מִצְרַ֫יִם
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
            משֶׁה
        
        עֵשָׂו
        
        פַּרְעֹה
        
        צִיּוֹן
        
        שָׁאוּל
        
        שְׁלֹמֹה
        
        שְׁמוּאֵל
        \end{minipage}
    \end{spacing}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Note finally that increasing the spacing (something I had desired originally anyway) turned out to be necessary in this case because the Hebrew words do not necessarily take up the same vertical space depending on which vowels are used. The result without increased line spacing was uneven columns.

Answer (score 4):

As @MS-SPO already mentioned in comments, beamer has its own column mechanism.

Internally, beamer places a bunch of minipages besides each other (like letters in a word) to create these columns. This means you could switch the language within the columns environment and get the columns in reversed order:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}

%Languages
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}{Arial}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Vocabulaire: Chap. 2}
    
        \begin{columns}
                 \selectlanguage{hebrew}
                 \begin{column}{0cm}
                 \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    אַבְרָהָם
            
    אַהֲרֹן
    
    דָּוִד
    
    יְהוּדָה
    
    יהוה
    
    יְהוֹשׁוּעַ
    
    יוֹסֵף
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    יַעֲקֹב
    
    יִצְחָק
    
    יְרוּשָׁלַ֫םִ
    
    יִרְמְיָ֫הוּ
    
    יִשְׂרָאֵל
    
    כְּנַעַן
    
    מִצְרַ֫יִם
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    משֶׁה
    
    עֵשָׂו
    
    פַּרְעֹה
    
    צִיּוֹן
    
    שָׁאוּל
    
    שְׁלֹמֹה
    
    שְׁמוּאֵל
    \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use babel and the columns will automatically be in reverse order. And also no dirty hacks necessary for the right margin:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}



%Languages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main]{french}
\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}
\babelfont{sf}{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{Arial}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Vocabulaire: Chap. 2}
    
{    \selectlanguage{hebrew}
        \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    אַבְרָהָם
            
    אַהֲרֹן
    
    דָּוִד
    
    יְהוּדָה
    
    יהוה
    
    יְהוֹשׁוּעַ
    
    יוֹסֵף
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    יַעֲקֹב
    
    יִצְחָק
    
    יְרוּשָׁלַ֫םִ
    
    יִרְמְיָ֫הוּ
    
    יִשְׂרָאֵל
    
    כְּנַעַן
    
    מִצְרַ֫יִם
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    משֶׁה
    
    עֵשָׂו
    
    פַּרְעֹה
    
    צִיּוֹן
    
    שָׁאוּל
    
    שְׁלֹמֹה
    
    שְׁמוּאֵל
    \end{column}
        \end{columns}}
   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for this answer. I was able to replicate it and noticed that the babel option works better as regards the placement of the Hebrew vowels.

The one catch to this solution is that one needs to design each column, whereas in the past I have used the multicol package to automatically calculate the length of each column, since sometimes there are more or less words in the list. Thus, from one slide deck to the next it was a matter of a single copy-paste. Do you think such a solution is possible with a right-to-left language?

Comment: @jejb A beamer slide should be carefully constructed in order to best convey its information. Automatic approaches like automatic column or page breaking usually lead to subpar results. If you insist on an automatic solution, the babel approach works just as well with multicols.

Comment: It is worth noting that while LuaLaTeX makes possible the desired functionality regarding the right-to-left ordering of columns, it does not perform as well as XeLateX for the positioning of the Hebrew vowels.

Comment: @jejb I wouldn't use xelatex with beamer. This can cause a lot of problems. Missing text on note pages, incorrect uncovering of overlays ... and many of the non-text links are just dirty hacks in xelatex.